# Not showing second option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get second option value print, how can I possible in this way. please update code below.

```js
$('#select1').change(function() {

  var form_data = {
    userName: $('#select1').val()
  };
  var data1 = '<select class="selectpicker form-control m-b" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-primary" name="site" id="siteSelect" required><option selected disabled > Please select site </option><option value="942">DEHIWALA</option><option value="941">KOLLUPITIYA</option><option value="944">MORATUWA</option><option value="940">PRIME LAND</option><option value="943">RATHMALANA</option></select>';

  document.getElementById('selsear').innerHTML = data1;
});

$('#siteSelect').change(function() {

  var form_data = {
    userName: $('#siteSelect').val()
  };

  alert(form_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<div id="selsear">
</div>
```

How to print second option ( I created in side javascript ) value?

please tell me how can i get value from second option.

Comment: use event delegation. change `$('#siteSelect').change(function() {` to `$(document).on('change','#siteSelect',function() {`

Comment: change `$('#siteSelect').change(function()` to `$(document).on("change", '#siteSelect', function()`

Comment: Do you want to get the value from the second select box or the second value in the first search box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#select1').change(function() {

  var form_data = {
    userName: $('#select1').val()
  };
  var data1 = '<select class="selectpicker form-control m-b" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-primary" name="site" id="siteSelect" required><option selected disabled > Please select site </option><option value="942">DEHIWALA</option><option value="941">KOLLUPITIYA</option><option value="944">MORATUWA</option><option value="940">PRIME LAND</option><option value="943">RATHMALANA</option></select>';

  document.getElementById('selsear').innerHTML = data1;
});

$(document).on('change', '#siteSelect', function() {

  var form_data = {
    userName: $('#siteSelect').val()
  };

  alert(form_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<div id="selsear">
</div>
```

1. Use event delegation for dynamically created elements
2. Use `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you are adding listener before adding the `siteSelect` item to the dom.

Add the listener inside the change function of the first select element.

Your change function of `#select1` is called when any change of value happens in your `select1` element and as you are adding the `siteSelect` element inside `select1` and the element `siteSelect` is not added in the DOM until any change event is fired on the `select1` DOM.

Hence, when you are trying to add change event on `siteSelect` it fails as there is no `siteSelect` element in the DOM at the moment so, no change event listener is added and none is fired from `siteSelect`.

Further you are selecting the value of select element wrong you can get selected value like this `$('#select1 option:selected').val()` or `$('#select1 option:selected').text()` to get the text instead of value property.

One solution is what is shown below

```js
$('#select1').change(function() {

  var form_data = {
    userName: $('#select1 option:selected').val()
  };
  var data1 = '<select class="selectpicker form-control m-b" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-primary" name="site" id="siteSelect" required><option selected disabled > Please select site </option><option value="942">DEHIWALA</option><option value="941">KOLLUPITIYA</option><option value="944">MORATUWA</option><option value="940">PRIME LAND</option><option value="943">RATHMALANA</option></select>';

  document.getElementById('selsear').innerHTML = data1;
  
  $('#siteSelect').change(function() {

  var form_data = {
    userName: $('#siteSelect option:selected').val()
  };

  alert(form_data);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<div id="selsear">
</div>
```

Comment: You should always include an explanation to your solution

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I was adding. Its added now.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you update the innerHTML of `selsear` the handlers bound its previous children are removed (as they no longer exist). So we can either rebind those handlers, or delegate the event further up the DOM tree thanks to event bubbling.

When the change event happens on `selsear`s child select element, we do not capture it directly. Instead we bind the handler to the document and allow it to bubble up. When the event is caught, we check that it originated from our target element - in this case an element with the id of `siteSelect`.

```js
$('#select1').change(function() {
  var form_data = {
    userName: $('#select1').val()
  };
  var data1 = '<select class="selectpicker form-control m-b" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-primary" name="site" id="siteSelect" required><option selected disabled > Please select site </option><option value="942">DEHIWALA</option><option value="941">KOLLUPITIYA</option><option value="944">MORATUWA</option><option value="940">PRIME LAND</option><option value="943">RATHMALANA</option></select>';

  document.getElementById('selsear').innerHTML = data1;
});

$(document).on('change', '#siteSelect', function () {
    var form_data = {
      userName: $('#siteSelect').val()
    };

    alert(form_data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<div id="selsear">
</div>
```

EDIT: Not used jQuery in a while, and just seen that `delegate` is deprecated. Changed to use `on` method.